# Typescript, Angular 2 - Parse Json to object in http

Tags: json, angular, parsing, typescript, angular2-services

I have a file `location.json`, containing JSON string of the form:

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "places": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "city": "A",
          "state": "AB"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

I created classes of the form:

```
export class Location{
       constructor(public id: number,
        public places: Place[],
     }

export class Place {
        constructor(
        public id: number, 
        public city: string,
        public state: string
}
```

How do I parse the JSON string to object? I did something like this:

```
...
export class DashboardComponent {

  locations: Locations[];

  constructor(private locationService:LocationService) {
    this.getLocations() 
  }

  getLocations(){
      this.locationService.get('assets/location.json')
      .subscribe(res => this.location = res);
  }
```

Comment: maybe try with a JSON.Parse(res)

Comment: This did not map my json.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what's the result for the subsriber it can be:

```
.map(res => this.location = res.json().locations);
```

Or:

```
.subscribe(res => this.location = JSON.parse(res).locations);
```

But keep in mind that that won't instiantiate instances for your classes, it will only assign the values as regular js object which match the following:

```
interface Location {
    id: number;
    places: Place[];
}

interface Place {
    id: number;
    city: string;
    state: string;
}
```

If you want instances of the classes you'll need to do something like:

```
JSON.parse(res)
    .locations.map(location => new Location(location.id, 
        location.places.map(place => new Place(place.id, place.city, place.state)))
```

Comment: I got this error:  `EXCEPTION: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` when I did `JSON.parse`

Comment: Again, it depends what you're getting there. Add this: `console.log(res, typeof res)` to see what's the actual response

Answer (score 0):

usually you map response with `res => res.json()` somewhere in the service method but json should have a valid format, otherwise it won't parse.

Note, that response is an Object and you can't parse it but only body of the response.

```
  return this.http.get(url,options).map((response) => this.parseResponse(response))
        .catch((err) => this.handleError(err));

  private handleError(error: any) {
    let body = error.json();

    return Observable.throw(body);
  }

  private parseResponse(response: Response) {
    return response.json();
  }
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Thanks, but I still have seen the mapping...I should be able to `locations` in NgFor.

Comment: if it issues anything but json has a different structure, so you better transform the results

Comment: `.subscribe(res => this.locations = res.json().locations);`